# QueryString Link Help

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

How come when I put this code in my page to request the query string my page is returning a href of nothing?

Code In Page:

```
<a href='<% String.Format("book.aspx?id=" + Request.QueryString["id"]); %>'>Test</a>
```

Result:

```
<a href=''>Test</a>
```

Comment: @JonathanWood IDK checkout my profile, Ive accepted answers on all questions already.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: That happens sometimes.  There's a lot of caching on Stack Overflow.  It's often worth checking the profile first, perhaps if the person just recently accepted some of those answers (which, for a small number of questions, changes the percentage drastically).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `<%=` and not `<%` to output the result of the String.Format to the page. Right now you are just discarding the result.

Comment: Where Can I read more about whats the difference between <%=  and <%# and <%# etc Ive seen these all in code but dont know what they all mean.

Comment: @Bob, I forget what the tags are called actually and they are hard as hell to google (maybe ask another question?). Essentially `<% %>` just executes the code on the server side. `<%= %>` is similar to calling `Response.Write()` which will output the result directly to the page (which is what you want here). `<%# %>` is a data binding expression which you can read about here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx

Comment: +1 You know, I also find all the variations of these confusing. And, unfortunately, it's almost impossible to Google for this as Google is not very good with punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have the String.Format in there, all you need is this:

```
<a href="book.aspx?id=<%=Request.QueryString["id"] %>">Test</a>
```

Also, even though ASP.NET checks for potentially dangerous request values, it's good practice to either encode or validate values like this:

```
<a href="book.aspx?id=<%=Server.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString["id"]) %>">Test</a>
```

or

```
<a href="book.aspx?id=<%=Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]) %>">Test</a>
```